# Web browser - redirecting F1 (doesn't work always)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `jQuery` for redirect `F1-F10` keys in web browser (MFF or chrome):

```
$('*').live("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 112) 
  {
    document.getElementById('form:f1').click();
    return false;
  }
});
```

So, when I press `F1`, instead of browsers own `HELP` the button with ID `form:f1` is fired. 
And **it works properly, but sometimes not**.

E.g. 10 times I start the web app (browser) and redirecting is working properly, and at the 11th start of the browser, it doesn't work suddenly and I have to restart browser.

All other `javascript` or `jQuery` functions are working always, but redirecting doesn't.

Don't you know where could be the problem?

Comment: Please don't steal hotkeys from my browser.

Comment: Lucky me that my help shortcut is ⌘+?.

Comment: No choice, the functionality have to be on F-keys :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's hard to see what the exact problem is, there are problems or bad practices in all lines.

- There is no point binding a live event to all elements, instead do what live does, and take advantage of event bubbling. Only bind the keydown event of the document.
- Use `e.which` to check the pressed key, jQuery normalizes the event object, so it works in all browsers.
- For consistency, use jQuery selector instead of `document.getElementById`.
- Try to avoid using special characters in IDs, you're better off treating them as identifier names in most programming languages. Use `form_f1` instead of `form:f1`.
- Use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false`.

Also make sure that the focus is somewhere within your document when you press <kbd>F1</kbd>, i.e. it's not on the address bar or any other button/element of your browser UI.

If you're using `e.stopPropagation()` on keydown events anywhere, that would stop the event from bubbling up the DOM, falling back to default hotkey functionality.

The following code works for me consistently all the time in FireFox 5 and Google Chrome 12.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 112){
        $('#form_f1').click();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DarthJDG, your code works (so far i can't say if always or not), but I can't use `$('#form_f1').click();` because `form:f1` means, that is the button with ID `f1` on form ID `form`. I don't know how to tell it using your code..??

Comment: IDs should always be unique in your document, so there is no need for nested lookups. If you want duplications, use classes. `$('#form .f1')` would get you all elements with class `f1` under the form with ID `form`. For more info, just google jQuery selectors.

Comment: Actually, i have them unique and in addition `forceId="true"`, but `$('#form .f1')` and even `$('#f1')` doesn´t work, and `document.getElementById` does. Why do you think I shouldn't use `document.getElementById`??

Comment: `document.getElementById('form:f1').click();` works and `..('f1')..` doesn't :) In any case, your code + this piece of mine seems to work much better, thank you! :)